# What "lipper" means?

Tags: meaning

The word "lipper" is printed in my cloth. What the word means?

This is result of search on dictionary.com.

noun Nautical.
1  a slightly rough or ripply surface on a body of water.
2  spray from small waves.

But other dictionaleis don't have the word.

Comment: What makes you unsatisfied with the definition you found at dictionary.com?

Comment: I notice here - http://bitly.ws/9aoY - that other T-shirts in the line have names of drugs on them... Possibly it is one of the meanings mentioned in Urban Dictionary here - https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lipper

Comment: ... otherwise it is just the name of the manufacturer or some random word with no meaning.

Comment: Hilariously bad translations or silly English words on T-shirts made in East Asia [are a thing](https://www.boredpanda.com/funny-english-translations-t-shirt-fail-asia-broken-engrish/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic)

Comment: Is the cloth made into a garment and is the word repeated as a design? It would be good to have a better idea of the context.

Comment: In the design or on the selvedge? A picture would be useful?